# SQL Query for all students who purchased a book that is cited by a book that is higher price

Tags: sql, postgresql

So i have a student table with name and sid, which relates to sid in table buys. Buys also has a bookno field which relates to bookno in table cites (citations). Cites has a citedbookno field that relates to bookno in the table book.

Right now i only have all students who have purchased a book, but would like to refine it to show only those students who have bought a book that is cited by at least one book with a higher price. Im not sure exactly how to write the count query here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.sid, s.sname
FROM student s
WHERE s.sid IN (SELECT r.sid 
    FROM buys r
    WHERE b.bookno IN (SELECT c.bookno
               FROM cites c
                   WHERE c.citedbookno IN (SELECT b.bookno 
                           FROM book b
                           WHERE b.bookno = c.citedbookno)));
```

Comment: do your tables have any columns for the price? Could you show us the full structure?

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - as formatted text, not images.

Answer (score 0):

Simple version:

```
select      distinct student.sid, student.sname
from        student
            inner join
            buys
            on  buys.sid = student.sid
            inner join
            book
            on  book.bookno = buys.bookno
            inner join
            cites
            on  cites.citedbookno = book.bookno
            inner join
            book bookExpensive
            on  bookExpensive.bookno = cites.bookno
where       bookExpensive.price > book.price
```

This is the same, but might perform better:

```
select      student.sid, student.sname
from        student
where       exists(
                select      1
                from        buys
                            inner join
                            book
                            on  book.bookno = buys.bookno
                where       buys.sid = student.sid
                            and
                            exists(
                                select      1
                                from        cites
                                            inner join
                                            book bookExpensive
                                            on  bookExpensive.bookno = cites.bookno
                                where       cites.citedbookno = book.bookno
                                            and
                                            bookExpensive.price > book.price
                            )
            )
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `cites.citedbookno` is the `bookno` of a book being cited.

```
SELECT 
    s.sid,
    s.sname
FROM Student s
WHERE s.sid IN (
                   SELECT r.sid 
                   FROM buys r 
                   JOIN cites c ON r.bookno = c.citedbookno 
               );
```